# Problems changing incoming string to integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, integer

I have a rest api that that is getting a string sent to it. The problem is that I need to use this string (which will always be a number) for an id, which needs to be an integer. I am trying to accomplish this by turning the string into an integer when it is received. This is what I have been trying to do, but I get the error message listed bellow when I try:

```
def create
  respond_with @classroom = Classroom.create(classroom_params)
  if @classroom.save
    #do stuff
  else
    #do other stuff
  end
end

def classroom_params
  params.require(:classroom).permit(:period.to_i, :teacher.to_i, :subject.to_i)
end
```

Here is the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `to_i' for :period:Symbol):
app/controllers/api/v1/classroom_controller.rb:42:in `classroom_params'
app/controllers/api/v1/classroom_controller.rb:24:in `create'
```

Comment: How do you have your model setup?  What are the types of those attributes?

Comment: The strings being passed to the api are id numbers of a period table, a subject table, and a class table. These are then used to create a joint table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. `permit` method requires a list of symbols to allow. You can only do `classroom_params.map(&:to_i)` since you want all the parameters as integer. If there is anything in `classroom_params` that you want as string, you will have to convert the ones that you want as integers explicitly.

```
def create
  attributes = classroom_params
  @classroom = Classroom.create(:teacher_id => attributes[:teacher].to_i,
                                :student_id => attributes[:student].to_i,
                                :subject_id => attributes[:subject].to_i)
  respond_with 

  if @classroom.save
    #do stuff
  else
    #do other stuff
  end
end

def classroom_params
  params.require(:classroom).permit(:period, :teacher, :subject)
end
```

Comment: now it says `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Period(#) expected, got Fixnum(#)):` The strings being passed to the api are id numbers for specific tables. Rails uses these to create a joint table.

Comment: Then you don't have any option other than to specify them explicitly. See my edit